# Refresh list of drawables in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

When I add drawable resources to my project they do not show up in the list of drawables in the Reference Chooser.  I checked the R file and there are references for the files.

I have tried refreshing the project, cleaning the project, and fixing project properties and nothing seems to help.  Sometimes a couple will randomly show up in there, but not all of them.

The only consistent way I can get them to show up is to restart Eclipse.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Edit:  Further findings:

After some trials, I found an other inconvenient work around to he issue.  Turns out when importing multiple files into the project at once, Eclipse will only add the last one imported into the reference chooser.  So when I imported my images one at a time, they all show up properly!

Like I said, inconvenient considering the amount of images I have left to import, but maybe with this new information it may help nail down where the issue may be and a possible fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out some new info again.

Since I am doing a port from Blackberry, almost all of my images' filenames have uppercase letters in them, so I end up importing them all and then having to rename all the images after they are imported into the project.

I tried renaming all of my images before importing them all into the project.  To my delight, all of the images showed up right away in the reference chooser!  So it seems there is a problem when you import files and they cause errors with your project and allowing all of them to show up in the reference chooser.

So if you have to rename files, do it before import!
I'm just not entirely sure that this is the only cause for this issue but it has solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

I too faced the same problem. I added an image to the res/drawable-hdpi folder, cleaned the project and was able to see the name of the image in the left pane in Eclipse. But when I tried to use this image using Reference Chooser and looked under Drawable, I didn't find it.

I simply exited from Eclipse, and started it again. It was there! Like many things in computers, problems can be resolved simply by restarting!

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to fix this is to include the generated R class itself.